Building this docker image took more than 8 hours
I tried to build the following docker image from my conda environment. I tried many times and reduced a lot of packages but it's still taking the same time and it never stop building anway so i don't know when it will finish
# Use Miniconda3 as the base image
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Copy the environment.yml file to the container
COPY environment.yml /app

# Update the Conda environment from the environment.yml file
RUN conda env update -f /app/environment.yml

# Activate the environment and ensure the subsequent commands are run in this environment
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5000

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME MLFlow_Container

Evironment:
name: base
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.13
  - mlflow=1.30.0
  - tensorflow=2.4.0
  - numpy
  - scipy
  - protobuf
  - opencv
  - pyyaml
  - pillow
  - seaborn
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - requests
  - pip
  - pip:
      - absl-py==0.15.0
      - grpcio==1.32.0
      - sentencepiece==0.1.95
      - tqdm==4.55.1
      - ultralytics==8.0.0  # For YOLOv8 implementation by Ultralytics

It's taking more than 8 hours to build it and it's still building it! Any suggestion please?
